# Where can I get a array/list of items that follow certain rules

Tags: algorithm, validation, input

I'm learning to design algorithms and I usually have to both design the algorithm and the input to test it.

I was wondering if there is any resource where you can select the size of the input and some rules for its items such as (for example) sorted, increasing, 2D points, etc. It would be very handy.

Does it exist? where could I find this resource?

Comment: If you are learning to design algorithms, then you should learn how to fill an array yourself. sorted, random etc is pretty basic and code for that can be made in seconds (or minutes).

Comment: That's right. I mean, I can write a program to generate the array, but I was wondering if this exists as an application given that this must be a common resource needed by lots of people.

Comment: Perhaps look in the internet for a test-case generator for competitive programming, you may be able to find a tool that does that and it would work in your case. Competitive programmers who are problem-setters often generate their own test data.